# Creating dashboards in PowerBI with Json files

Tags: json, database, api, powerbi

I have an API key to access the data and I used Postman, GitHub and Visual Studio to get the results in JSON files.

I need to create a dashboard using PowerBI (ideally) and add the data I get from the API. The site we are getting this data from doesn't allow to access this data straight away, so from my understanding, I will need to create a database with the results from API and that database to be added to Power Bi.

I will also need to schedule some refresh times or something to have the data into Power BI as close as possible to live-data (or at list to schedule it to update a couple of times per day). Will this be possible without creating databases to store the data (just using JSON files that I already have and schedule a refresh from Power BI app)?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. As it stands, your question is too high level for this site.
Does this help you? https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4621/using-power-bi-with-json-data-sources-and-files/

Comment: Thank you very much. I am trying this now. That`s much easier than I thought. Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.